# C# Filestream unable to read word html properly

Tags: c#, encoding, ms-word

I am trying to publish articles written in Word on a website as html, I have a windows client that will convert the article to html and ship the html to a folder on the website, I then show the article in an IFrame. However in IE9 the images won't show because IE9 tries to convert them to vector graphics. I decided to remove the code from the html that's responsible for this and here starts my problem. After I modify and save the file I get garbage characters and these are displayed on the webpage too. However if I manually edit the file in notepad++ I don't get the same issues, How can I read a file saved in word as html using C# and not get these garbage chars?? here is my code

```
    private bool AdjustHtmlPageForIE9Images(FileInfo file)
    {
        bool success = true;
        try
        {
            string content = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
            //replace [if gte vml 1] with [if gte iesucksopd 1]
            content = content.Replace("[if gte vml 1]", "[if gte iesucksopd 1]");
            //replace [if !vml] with [if !iesucksopd]
            content = content.Replace("[if !vml]", "[if !iesucksopd]");
            //now write the file over
            File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

and this causes some garbage chars to be displayed.

Hi guys thanks for all the responses here is what I did to fix this

Hi Guys thanks for the responses finaly got it going, I had to open in FF and check the encoding and it was Western Windows-1252, then as SLaks sed pass GetEncoding(1252) in read and write operations here is the revised code.

```
    private bool AdjustHtmlPageForIE9Images(FileInfo file)
    {
        bool success = true;
        try
        {
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
            string content = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName,encoding);
            //replace [if gte vml 1] with [if gte iesucksopd 1]
            content = content.Replace("[if gte vml 1]", "[if gte iesucksopd 1]");
            //replace [if !vml] with [if !iesucksopd]
            content = content.Replace("[if !vml]", "[if !iesucksopd]");
            //now write the file over
            File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, content, encoding);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Isn't it just ridiculous that IE9 can't do such a simple thing as display html from word in an IFrame no wonder it's popularity keeps falling.

Comment: How can I figure out the files encoding?

Comment: @SLaks encoding is Western(Windows-1252)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass the encoding to `ReadAllText` and `WriteAllText`; otherwise, it will default to UTF8.

Pass `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the converted html file is UTF-8 or UTF-32 encoded, ReadAllText will detect it correctly then. Otherwise use ReadAllText overload to provide parameter with encoding used by the converted.